# Adding file to github:gist thats not text

Tags: git, github, gist

https://gist.github.com/1595572

I'm adding a ttf font to a github:gist so i can share it. the person above did it but I'm only seeing ways to add it as text. How might one go about adding the actual file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always create a gist with a dummy (text) file, clone it, delete the file and add the file (ttf font) you want and push.

This is what the person you have linked to has done. See the first commit: https://gist.github.com/1595572/8fe448cb122dfe75084ce1b48146f6cc6282e81d

Comment: can i do this through the website or do I need to use command line? how might one do this through command line if its the later?

Comment: this one is mine: https://gist.github.com/1695735 . there is no clone button though. I am new to git :S

Comment: @Tallboy - You can see a public url and a private url. Use the private url and run `git clone <private url>` from command line / terminal. You have to install git. Learn more about it if needed.